# Mysql query inactive user for previous week

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table action_info where every users click saving in. I need to get a count of inactive users for previous week. Here is the query for ACTIVE users:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT user_id ) as active_for_week FROM action_info 
     WHERE action_name = 'attack' 
     AND time >= (CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: you have to use the user table joined with action_info

Comment: Are all users in action_info?

Comment: All users in action info, I cant use my user's table because query will be veeery long by performance. I've already tried count all users from users table and after calculate, but performance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would exclude all users active in last week from users table, therefore giving you only inactive users. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ID NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM action_info 
        WHERE action_name = 'attack' 
        AND time >= (CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
)
```

UPDATE:

Without querying users table, you can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS not_active_last_week FROM action_info 
WHERE action_name = 'attack' AND user_id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM action_info 
    WHERE action_name = 'attack' 
    AND time >= (CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
)
```

which gives you number of all users that were active at some point, but NOT during the last week. 
Here's [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee5f3/5)

Comment: Not really, if user was active before last week, and during last week, this query would count him in too. I have updated my answer, please have a look.